# Program that hides the Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-7

I am using windows 7 and I have automatic updates turned off. I used to be notified when a new update was available but for some months now this has stopped (no idea why....still have the 'ask before downloading when there is a new update' option turned on).

So every time I want to update windows I go to the update center and I press to see all available updates. along with all the updates there is always the windows 10 update selected and I have to deselect it every time I want to update.

Is there a program that hides that update so that I won't have to deselect it every time?

Comment: Since this week there's an option to opt-out, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe not yet in my country or I haven't found that yet. How is that possible?

Comment: I'm sorry I already opted out, otherwise I'd have provided a screenshot.

Comment: @ThomasWeller no problem. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Never10](https://www.grc.com/never10.htm) did exactly this in the past. It is gratis.

> Never10 does NOT prevent the installation of Windows updates, including
>   the infamous Get Windows 10 (GWX) update KB3035583.  Never10 simply
>   employs Microsoft's documented and sanctioned configuration settings to
>   instruct it NOT to change the installed version of Windows.

Since this week, at least here in Germany, the Windows 10 update itself provides an option to opt-out and disable the nag screen.